What is the most effective method for periodically calling an API in the background?
I have application where I use TimeTask for counting timeFromLastOrderLoad.
      val t: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                timeFromLastOrderLoad += 1
                if (timeFromLastOrderLoad >= reloadingPeriod) {
                    timeFromLastOrderLoad = 0
                    activity?.get()?.runOnUiThread {
                        getStatus()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        reloadOrdersTimer?.schedule(t, 0, 1000)

Function getStatus goes with other API calls like readyToGetDataCall() etc.
So every 15 seconds my applications makes API requests. If application is in background I still need to make these calls every 15 seconds and checks if something changes then play music like bell.
Sometimes it work on background, sometimes not. I understand it because of cleaning memory on my phone.
I do know it is not good approach I know we could have FCM with back intergration, but for now I have that propositions:

Create WorkManager which will do the same job on background with the same approach TimerTask or with using suspend delay(15.seconds), but still if I understand well from documentation Coroutine workmanager will be cleaned with the same manner as actual approach.
When app goes to background create Foreground Service, which should live much longer than 2 previous approchaes (actual and workmanger), when it back to foreground use actual approach of getting data.
? I'm not sure I have other options if I still can't rely on the solutions with  FCM

Thanks for any approaches that you think could be the best.
How to solve this issue?

"I do know it is not good approach" -- then either change the requirements to poll much less frequently or adopt FCM. Users have spoken very loudly that they hate apps that continuously drain the battery in the background. Google and device manufacturers have gone to great lengths to prevent developers from creating battery-draining apps. Rather than fight Google, device manufacturers, and your entire user base... come up with a better plan.

I will do it, after we will have time for it. It is not let's say public application more like private company app, so what i need for now it's find better approach and if we have free time to implement FCM we will for sure. So I kindly ask you if you have any proposition, share. But anyway thanks for that comment this is true for sure, no doubt!
